# Unable to edit comment on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: screen shot 1]
I can't tell if this is a bug or user fail. Samsung note 5 version 1.0.89.

*One day later...*

I tried again just now and this time I get the edit option.

[image: screen shot 2]

Comment: No repro on v1.0.89, but one curious thing is, the "delete" icon seems missing on your screenshot, suggesting that you're logged out... For whatever reason (I guess I have seen this bug report before about sudden logout)

Comment: Go to setting. Find the app. Clear data. And login again. I just had the same problem. :-)

Comment: The app options are hidden by the system default options. It is not a problem with the app.

Comment: Testing comment edit.

Comment: @user I found a much less destructive solution...uninstall and reinstall.